# how to fix openssl SSL_connect SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL errror in git clone enterprise repository when behind a proxy?

Tags: git, ubuntu, curl, proxy

I have an Ubuntu 18.04 VM in VMWare. This VM connects to internet behind a proxy. When I'm trying to git clone a repository from my enterprise github account, it gives the following error:

**OenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to {my github enterprise url}**

I get the same error when trying to curl the same git url.

I have tried configuring the git proxy by:
git config --global http.proxy http://myproxy:port
git config --global https.proxy http://myproxy:port

The connection to proxy is successful but there is an error in connection to https://{github enterprise repository}

I expect the "git clone" command to ask my credentials for the repository but it gives the openssl error.

Comment: Are you using ssh or http url to clone the git repo?

Comment: I am using https url, it is like "https://github.dev."

Comment: Found a solution: bypass proxy for this enterprise git will work